# File Vault Paused

Tags: macos, high-sierra, encryption, filevault

Im trying to update to High Sierra, But can't because my file vault is currently encrypting. (so says the error message) However, when I check the status, it shows that it is "paused" and has been like that for over a week. Ive looked around, troubleshooted as much as i could and can't get anything to work. Ive tried the Sudo command and repairing the Disk... Nothing works... PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an Apple laptop? If so, you need to connect it to a charger for the encryption to continue.